# What's wrong with my "import module based on string" file

Tags: python

```
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Example_Mission.py'; 'Example_Mission' is not a package
```

Here's my code.

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
  for filename in files:
    if filename[len(filename)-3:len(filename)] == ".py":
      Mission = importlib.import_module("Example_Mission.py") # Seems useless in this big loop, but I'll change this later.
      Mission.Init()
```

I've added a blank `__init__.py` to the current dictionary, but I still get an error. Any clue why?
(Some of it may seem useless, i'll implement it later)

All of the files mentioned are on the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module named "Example_Mission" lives in a file called "Example_Mission.py", so you need to specify the module name, not the filename, as in:

```
Mission = importlib.import_module("Example_Mission")
```